# set space on both sides of line plot ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, line

I'm having trouble setting empty spaces on both sides of a ggplot2 graph. Here is the data I'm starting with:

```
ade <- c(10,7,5,9,6,6,9,4,9,6,5,9,8,7,6,12,7,9,5,5)
adef<-cbind(c(2:21),c(ade/28))
colnames(adef)<-c("pos","f")
adef<-data.frame(adef)
```

When I plot this very simply, It looks fine.

```
ggplot(data=adef, aes(x=pos, y=f)) +
+     ylim(0,1) + 
+     geom_line()
```

[image: simple ggplot]

However, unexpected things happen when I attempt to change the number of ticks and labels:

```
ggplot(data=adef, aes(x=pos, y=f)) +
ylim(0,1) + 
 scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22"),
                  labels=c("2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21",""))+
geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot after setting scale_x_discrete]

I would like to add an empty margin/space to the right so that the left and right part of the graph look the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you looking for a `scale_x_continuous` instead? eg:

```
ggplot(data=adef, aes(x=pos, y=f)) +
  ylim(0,1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=2:22, labels=c(as.character(2:21), "")) +
  geom_line()
```

and maybe `xlim()` and/or `expand` argument in `scale_*()` may help.

Comment: you can add `limits=c(#,#)` right in`scale_[x|y]_*`